# Azure Function - Can you acccess IServiceProvider Before Function Scope?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Hi I have a use case that would be desireable to gain access to IServiceProvider before a function invoke in azure function project.

Attempts:

1. Using a IWebJobsStartup cs file, I am able to access the serviceCollection before a function invoke. at the end I have attempted this code

   ```
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAccountAPITests>();
   ```

with in error message "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.IFileLoggingStatusManager' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Diagnostics.HostFileLoggerProvider'.'"

The only time I can access IServiceCollection so far is with in my funciton

```
 public TestAutomationFunction
    (
        IServiceProvider rootServiceProvider
    )
    {

        _integrationTestService = rootServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IIntegrationTestService>();
    }
```

This works fine, But the issues is functions are scoped, and thus anything that is resolved with in it will be tied to its same scope.

I did my best to draw a viso of why I dont have this problem in ASP.net and why i do in functions.

I would like to either access IServiceProvider Before a function invoke to ensure my services are not in the same scope. Or after the function is invoked resolve my services with in a spereate scope.

I can of course just change Package X singleton to a scoped, but my use case is not so simple as its deep in my stack i would have to do that all the way down.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doenst quite answer my question but it makes my question a mute point.

"Do not resolve a scoped service from a singleton. It may cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests. It's fine to resolve a singleton service from a scoped or transient service."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#service-lifetimes

I am going to have re work my stack to not allow this to happen, after that I wont have to worry about this issue.